# username field is blank in loadUserByUsername in UserDetailsServiceImpl

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using spring security for authentication.
Problem is all the time i am getting username as empty string. I even search about it all i get is i have to follow standard name for the fields like j_username and j_password which i am already doing.

Here is my login page -

```
<form id="signin" role="form" name="loginForm" method="POST"
    action='<c:url value="j_spring_security_check"></c:url>'>
    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><spring:message code="login.form.head.social.msg" text="Sign in with your social account"></spring:message></legend>
        <a href='<c:url value="/auth/facebook"></c:url>'
            class="btn social icon-facebook col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 pull-right">
            <i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x pull-left"></i>
            <spring:message code="login.social.facebook"></spring:message>
        </a> <a href="#"
            class="btn social icon-gplus col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5"><i
            class="fa fa-google-plus-square fa-2x pull-left"></i><spring:message code="login.social.googleplus"></spring:message> </a>
    </fieldset>
    <hr>
    <fieldset style="margin-top: 20px;">
        <legend>
            <spring:message code="login.form.head.register.msg" text="Login with your registered account"></spring:message>
        </legend>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">@</span> <input type="email"
                    class="form-control" id="email" placeholder='<spring:message code="placeholder.email" text="Password"></spring:message>'
                    name="j_username">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i
                    class="fa fa-key fa-rotate-90"></i></span> <input type="password"
                    class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="<spring:message code="placeholder.password" text="Password"></spring:message>"
                    name="j_password">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <button type="submit"
                    class="btn btn-primary pull-right col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <spring:message code="btn.login" text="Login"></spring:message> 
                </button>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label> <input type="checkbox" id="remember-me"
                        name="_spring_security_remember_me">
                        <spring:message code="link.rememberme" text="Remember me"></spring:message>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <a href="#" class="login-link">
                    <spring:message code="link.resetpassword" text="Reset password !"></spring:message>
                </a> <a href="#"
                    class="login-link pull-right">
                    <spring:message code="link.registerhere" text="Register here !"></spring:message>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

My loadUserByUsername method. 
I have added comment at logger.info where i am printing username and i see an empty string ie. printing "load user by username - "

```
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        logger.info("load user by username - "+username);  //Here username is blank
        User user = getUserByEmail(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No user found with username: " + username);
        }
        SimpleUserDetailsVO principal = SimpleUserDetailsVO.getBuilder()
                .firstName(user.getFname())
                .id(user.getId())
                .lastName(user.getLname())
                .password(user.getPassword())
                .role(user.getRole())
                .socialSignInProvider(user.getSignInProvider())
                .username(user.getEmail())
                .build();

        return principal;
    }
```

in this method i have logged username and getting empty string.

Here is my security context

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityContext extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private UserServiceImpl userServiceImpl;

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler customAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
                //Spring Security ignores request to static resources such as CSS or JS files.
                .ignoring()
                    .antMatchers("/resources/**");
    }

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                //Configures form login
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/Home")
                    .failureUrl("/Home?loginError=true")
                    .successHandler(customAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/Home")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
                //Configures the logout function
                .and()
                    .logout()
                        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                        .logoutUrl("/j_spring_security_logout")
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/Home?logout=true")
                        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                //Configures url based authorization
                .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                        //Anyone can access the urls
                        .antMatchers(
                                "/Home"
                        ).permitAll()
                        //The rest of the our application is protected.
                        .antMatchers("/Admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .antMatchers("/Learner/**").hasRole("LEARNER")
                        .antMatchers("/Teacher/**").hasRole("TEACHER")
                        .antMatchers("/Institute/**").hasRole("INSTITUTE")
                //Adds the SocialAuthenticationFilter to Spring Security's filter chain.
                .and()
                    .apply(new SpringSocialConfigurer());
    }

    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(userServiceImpl)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(10);
    }
}
```

here is onStartup method of Application initializer

```
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)
            throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(MyApplicationContext.class);
        rootContext.setServletContext(servletContext);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(rootContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");

        EnumSet<DispatcherType> dispatcherTypes = EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD);

        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);

        FilterRegistration.Dynamic characterEncoding = servletContext.addFilter("characterEncoding", characterEncodingFilter);
        characterEncoding.addMappingForUrlPatterns(dispatcherTypes, true, "/*");

        FilterRegistration.Dynamic security = servletContext.addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain", new DelegatingFilterProxy());
        security.addMappingForUrlPatterns(dispatcherTypes, true, "/*");

//        FilterRegistration.Dynamic sitemesh = servletContext.addFilter("sitemesh", new ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter());
//        sitemesh.addMappingForUrlPatterns(dispatcherTypes, true, "/");

        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
    }
```

Comment: Not sure why the username is empty. Could you log the login request at debug level for package `org.springframework.security` and include it in your question?

Comment: @Ravi Kumar : I am also facing similar problem. Did you get a solution?

Comment: In my case it was a spelling mistake @Ashwin

Answer (score 4):

Spring Security allows you to customize your form loggin, but you have to map some stuff for it like username and password parameters. Here is an example of this configuration in `security-context.xml`:

```
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/home**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="isAuthenticated()" />

    <form-login login-page="/login"
                authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true"
                default-target-url="/index" 
                username-parameter="username"
                password-parameter="password"/>


    <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/login" />
```

notice that there is a `username-parameter` and `password-parameter` configuration, this might be your problem. Good Luck